# I cannot use my guest session on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, login, guest-session

Today I noticed that whenever I try to log into as a guest, the system hangs. This happens in both cases - when I try to log-in as guest in log-in screen and when I click "Guest session" upper-right corner menu option.

It might be important that I recently had big problem with upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04 - the system was completely inaccessible and I was forced to use live USB and a recovery procedure described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery to make system start again.

What could be the problem here?

EDIT: I noticed that the attempt to log in as a guest produces this in syslog:

```
Jan  3 15:52:59 marek-GA-990XA-UD3 systemd[1888]: Starting Default.
Jan  3 15:52:59 marek-GA-990XA-UD3 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 132.
Jan  3 15:52:59 marek-GA-990XA-UD3 kernel: [   17.985371] audit_printk_skb: 39 callbacks suppressed
Jan  3 15:52:59 marek-GA-990XA-UD3 kernel: [   17.985374] audit: type=1400 audit(1451832779.452:25): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=1897 comm="xrdb" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
Jan  3 15:52:59 marek-GA-990XA-UD3 kernel: [   17.998050] audit: type=1400 audit(1451832779.464:26): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=1912 comm="id" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
Jan  3 15:52:59 marek-GA-990XA-UD3 kernel: [   17.998057] audit: type=1400 audit(1451832779.464:27): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=1912 comm="id" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
Jan  3 15:52:59 marek-GA-990XA-UD3 kernel: [   17.999409] audit: type=1400 audit(1451832779.464:28): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=1913 comm="xhost" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
Jan  3 15:52:59 marek-GA-990XA-UD3 kernel: [   18.003125] audit: type=1400 audit(1451832779.468:29): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=1916 comm="unity_support_t" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
Jan  3 15:52:59 marek-GA-990XA-UD3 kernel: [   18.007685] audit: type=1400 audit(1451832779.472:30): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=1921 comm="id" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
Jan  3 15:52:59 marek-GA-990XA-UD3 kernel: [   18.007693] audit: type=1400 audit(1451832779.472:31): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=1921 comm="id" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
Jan  3 15:52:59 marek-GA-990XA-UD3 kernel: [   18.009047] audit: type=1400 audit(1451832779.476:32): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=1922 comm="xhost" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
Jan  3 15:52:59 marek-GA-990XA-UD3 kernel: [   18.013074] audit: type=1400 audit(1451832779.480:33): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=1927 comm="xdg-user-dirs-u" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
Jan  3 15:52:59 marek-GA-990XA-UD3 kernel: [   18.013081] audit: type=1400 audit(1451832779.480:34): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=1927 comm="xdg-user-dirs-u" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create" addr=none
```

Comment: Do you have any customization files in `/etc/guest-session`?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I don't even have `/etc/guest-session` directory. Should I?

Comment: No, it's [optional](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession). ;) But then we know that the cause is not such a badly configured file.

Comment: Does your root partition (,/ and /tmp ) have enough free space?

Comment: @totti yes, it does. But I edited my question with a syslog fragment that can be relevant.

Comment: It seems my problem has been solved by upgrading Ubuntu from 15.04 to 15.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the lightdm-guest-session file in

```
/etc/apparmor.d
```

has been corrupted or been deleted. There should be a file present named lightdm-guest-session without extension and with the following inside:

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor
# Profile for restricting lightdm guest session

#include <tunables/global>

/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session {   
# Most applications are confined via the main abstraction   
#include <abstractions/lightdm>

# chromium-browser needs special confinement due to its sandboxing  
#include <abstractions/lightdm_chromium-browser>  }
```

**The lines with #include are not comments but needed!**